# top hat filter matlab without the morphological part

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to use the top hat filter, as part of an assignment. I have read about the filter to understand its working, but the question has specifically mentioned not to use imtophat function from matlab, as they say it implements a morphological top hat filter. Is it possible to implement a plain top hat filter using that function? Or is there a way to implement it by code in matlab. Your help is much appreciated. My apologies if the question is very rudimentary.

The following questions discuss to an extent about the filters, but not exactly the answer am looking for.

[Applying the top hat filter to the inside of the edge of a region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418245/applying-the-top-hat-filter-to-the-inside-of-the-edge-of-a-region)

[Using imtophat in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777264/using-imtophat-in-matlab)

Actually the input to the function should the be the inner circle radius of the top hat filter. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a linear top-hat filter, just use [`filter2()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html), and pass in an all-ones matrix as the filter kernel.

Comment: Does it work the same way as a top hat filter? with concentric circles?